# Puppet conditional only if file exists in a particular directory

Tags: automation, puppet, devops

I have the following file resource in my puppet manifest:

```
file{
  'example.dat'
  path   => "/path/to/example.dat",
  owner  => devops,
  mode   => "0644",
  source => "/path/to/example.txt" 
}
```

I want to run the above snippet only when the `.txt` file is present in a particular directory. Otherwise, I do not want the snippet to run.

How do I go about doing that in puppet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you would create a [custom fact](https://puppet.com/docs/facter/3.9/custom_facts.html#adding-custom-facts-to-facter) that returns true when the directory in question satisfies your condition. For example:

```ruby
Facter.add('contains_txt') do
  setcode do
    ! Dir.glob("/path/to/dir/*.txt").empty?
  end
end
```

Then you would write:

```puppet
if $facts['contains_txt'] {
  file { 'example.dat':
    path   => "/path/to/example.dat",
    owner  => devops,
    mode   => "0644",
    source => "/path/to/example.txt",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the built-in function `find_file`:

```
if find_file('path-to-your-file') {
  # do something here if your file exists
}
```

Docs: https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html